# Read full client's request using java.nio selectors

Tags: java, nio

I'm writing a nio based http server. I need to collect full client's request before passing it to worker threads.

Which is the best way to collect full client's request in SelectionKey.OP_READ?

For now I'm thinking about doubling ByteBuffer attached to selector's key:

```
while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
    ...
    if(key.isAcceptable()) {
        ...
        key.attach(ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE));
    }
    if(key.isReadable()) {
        SocketChannel clientsc = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();
        if(buffer.remaining() < MIN_BUFFER_SIZE) {
            buffer = grow(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE * 2);
            key.attach(buffer);
        }
        clientsc.read(buffer);
        ...
    }
}
```

But this solution looks not optimal. Is there a better way?

Comment: Make the buffer big enough for the biggest request. But there are other problems here. Code with a read() call that doesn't store the result in a variable and then test that variable cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: Since it's http server, I don't know the biggest request size. Moreover, request sizes would vary greatly for sure. Big initial buffers would be waste of memory. Code is more like pseudocode, so don't mind errors.

Comment: Since the HTTP header consists of lines, the best solution would be to have a buffer for a line rather than a complete request and parse each line right after completion. Parsed information can be stored far more efficient.